# jQuery on multiple of the same divs, without using unique ID's?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Problem in short: I'm trying to make a simple show/hide toggle work on just the element you click on, while right now all (13) divs get affected by the function.

Structure of each div looks like this

```
<div class="selectbox">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <p>
        Content
    </p>
</div>
```

With this jquery code

```
$('.selectbox h5').click(function(){
         $('div.selectbox,p,span').toggle();
         $('.selectbox').toggle();
    });
```

So right now, the jquery works. But obviously, does its work on every "selectbox" div on the page. How can I make this work on just the element I click on, *without using a unique id for every "selectbox" div?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.selectbox h5').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().find('p,span').toggle(); 
     $(this).parent().toggle(); // this line should probably be removed 
});
```

Comment: the 'p,span' line isn't useless ;)
Works perfectly as you posted it, but not without that line

Comment: I was wondering. The last line is probably not desired in that case (if you'd want to toggle the thing back).

Comment: And you might be interested by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250251/what-jquery-based-table-plugin-can-hide-sub-rows/12250417#12250417) also.

Comment: Pretty much yes, with multiple checkboxes being the content.

Answer (score 3):

use `$(this)` -

```
$('.selectbox h5').click(function(){

  $(this).closest('.selectbox, p, span').toggle();
  //$('.selectbox').toggle();

});
```

Comment: We posted the same solution at the same time. I can't resist upvoting your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use the keyword `this` in your function, it represents the item that triggered the event. In this case your H5.

```
$('.selectbox h5').click(function(){
         $(this).closest('.selectbox').toggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple..

if you want the parent DIV to toggle then just use
`$(this).parent().toggle();`
in your function.
p.e.: If you want to work with the `<p>` in your div you may address it like `$('p', $(this).parent()).toggle();`